# Angular 4: Call non-angular function from Service in index.html

Tags: function, angular, call, zone.js

I created a non-angular function in my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    ...
}

const myFunction = function(){
    alert ( 'test' );
}
```

And now, I want to call **myFunction** from the index.html, so I put this in my **index.html**

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){ myFunction(); }, 5000);</script>
```

And I take this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at index.html:15
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:414)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:181)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:476)
    at timer (zone.js:1491)
(anonymous) @ index.html:15
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:414
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:181
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:476
timer @ zone.js:1491
```

How I could call **myFunction**?

Comment: Why not just make the function a method of the service?

Comment: because it is loaded in Chromium Embedded Framework

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
declare var myFunction;
```

after the imports.

Comment: I added "declare var myFunction: () => void;" because your declaration got an error, but it still same, just the error changed in Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at (index):13

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker? (Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular template)